# FlatList RenderItem image not showing

Tags: android, react-native, mobile, expo

I was developing a mobile application in my course when I got into this problem: I set an image from my API with `<Image source={{ uri: item.thumbnail_url }} />` but it doesn't show the image at all (when I use local images and other links it is possible to show the images)

That's my code:

```
      <FlatList
        style={styles.list}
        data={spots}
        keyExtractor={spot => spot._id}
        horizontal
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <View style={styles.listItem}>
            <Image style={styles.thumbnail} source={{ uri: item.thumbnail_url }} />
            <Text style={styles.company}>{item.company}</Text>
            <Text style={styles.price}>{item.price ? `R$${item.price}/dia` : `GRATUITO`}</Text>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => handleNavigate(item._id)} style={styles.button}>
              <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Solicitar reserva</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        )}
      />
```

StyleSheet:

```
  thumbnail: {
    width: 200,
    height: 120,
    resizeMode: 'cover',
    borderRadius: 2,
  },
```

I don't know why it is not working, my code is the same as my teacher's code

Comment: are you sure the url from the item is valid and working?

Comment: I'm pretty sure. When I open the URL in my browser it does work

Comment: does it work on your emulator/device? check if there are any errors when loading the image (see [the docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/image#onerror))

Comment: No, it doesn't work in my device for some reason, but the image is indeed there in the API, I'm just not able to insert it into the <Image /> tag. Also there are no errors